# Replace Function for specific values

Tags: sql, oracle, trim

I have a table like this:

1. Article
2. Date
3. Status
4. Code

In the column "Status" are values like '00', '01', 'OB'
In the column "Code" are values like:

- [05]+000569
- [1B] 5555
- 690KB
- -859

I am just interested for rows where "Status" = '00'.
The status '00' shows just values like [05]+000569.
These values should be trimmed with the following function:

```
select replace(regexp_substr(Code, '(^|[+])[0-9]+'), '+', '')
```

How can I build a SELECT SQL with this function just for rows where "Status" = '00' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see.  You want a `case` expression:

```
select (case when status = '00' then replace(regexp_substr(Code, '(^|[+])[0-9]+'), '+', '')
        end)
```

Answer (score 1):

"Trim" for `status = '00'`, don't for other statuses:

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN status = '00'                                              --> trim
          THEN                                                            --> for
             REPLACE (REGEXP_SUBSTR (Code, '(^|[+])[0-9]+'), '+', '')     --> '00'
          ELSE
             code                                                         --> else, do nothing
       END
          AS code
  FROM your_table
```